# How can I get a particular document data from fire store collection by ID?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**I need to get data from collection based on Id but I'm unable to fetch details.
I have tried certain methods but none worked as expected.**

Example 1

```
return this.db.collection("customers/", id).snapshotChanges();
```

It says to pass odd numbers of segment

My function

```
this.auth.getUserDetails(this.userid).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Example 2

```
return this.db.collection('customers')
      .doc(id)
      .get();
```

What would be the better way to fetch and display data?

Comment: Example 1 will definitely fail.  What's wrong with example 2? That looks like it will work, as long as `id` has a valid document ID string.

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this:

```
// Assuming ID is passed as an argument.
this.db.doc(`costumers/${id}`).snapshotChanges();
```

The reason why you're getting problems is because you're using `collection` instead of `doc`.

Comment: You can use .collection().doc() (I do it all the time)... BUT... the string provided to .doc() needs to be a PATH, not just an ID, so:

return this.db.collection('customers').doc("/" + id).get();